# Is there a way to intercept call button (earphone image) in contacts details in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, addressbook, abperson

I have a problem with contact details from AdressBook.
I use method `personViewController:shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:property:identifier:` to get selected number but when user tap on earphone image, I can't get selected number.
Is there a way to do this?
This earphone button exist only in iOS7.

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation by Apple? If there is no delegate call that allows you to intercept this, this won't be possible. And I am pretty sure, there is none.

Comment: You are right, there is nothing about this in Apple documentations.

Comment: I thought so, since it is an "intimate" system feature. Your app is probably not supposed to know when somebody is called due (privacy).

Comment: I have found a way to prevent the button to appear and this solved my problem.